# html toggle div content in table row

Tags: php, jquery, html

i saw this code and i want know how to hide the div content after clicking the same button. i tried placing .toggle() but i dont know where to put it. i'm still learning javascript and jquery and i'm practicing a lot of problems.

js:

```
$(document).delegate('input[type="button"]','click',function(){
    $('[colspan="5"]').parent('tr').remove();
    $(this).parents('tr').after('<tr/>').next().append('<td colspan="5"/>').children('td').append('<div/>').children().css('background','#f0f0f0').html($('#content').html());
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/4FKCa/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try this:

```
$('input[type="button"]').on('click', function(){

  // check if its a toggle by asking if it exists and is next to my TR
  if($(this).parent('td').parent('tr').next('tr').children('td#temp').length === 1){

    // toggle the td
    $('td#temp').toggle();

  } else {

    // remove other content divs
    $('td#temp').parent().remove();

    // perform insertion of content div
    $(this).parents('tr')
          .after('<tr/>')
          .next().append('<td id="temp" colspan="5"/>')
          .children('td')
          .append('<div/>')
          .children()
          .css('background','#f0f0f0')
          .html($('#content').html());
  }
});
```

Comments explain the code.